# Converting Varchar to Int in a sub query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query some thing like this

```
DECLARE @patientId INT

SET @patientId = 0

IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(TRN02, 1, CHARINDEX('-', TRN02) - 1)
          FROM   EDI_X12.dbo.X12_TRN
          WHERE  X12_Interchange_GUID = 'd6803485-3f46-485c-8288-2cfc98ec7088'
                 AND TRN02 LIKE '%-%')) 
BEGIN 
SET @patientId = (SELECT TOP 1 SUBSTRING(TRN02, 1, CHARINDEX('-', TRN02) - 1)
                  FROM   EDI_X12.dbo.X12_TRN
                  WHERE  X12_Interchange_GUID = @px12_interchange_guid
                         AND TRN02 LIKE '%-%') 
END
```

The value for `TRN02` is `112345-6458PT` Here `'6457PT'` is `patientID` the column is defined as INT
and how do i convert varchar to int in this particular query?

I want to save '6457PT' as patientid in INT field

Thanks in advance

Naveen

Comment: is it like from '112345-6458PT' you want to extract '6458'??

Comment: You don't need the `EXISTS` check. Just use `SELECT  TOP 1 @patientId = SUBSTRING`. If no rows match no assignment is made. Also why no `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @patientId int;

SELECT @patientId = CAST(SUBSTRING(TRN02, 1, CHARINDEX('-', TRN02) - 1) as INT)
      FROM   EDI_X12.dbo.X12_TRN
      WHERE  X12_Interchange_GUID = 'd6803485-3f46-485c-8288-2cfc98ec7088'
             AND TRN02 LIKE '%-%'

IF @patientId is null
BEGIN
     SET @patientId = 0;
END
```

In this way you have only one select instaed two( you don't need to check if the row exist).
But you cannot cast the value **6458PT** to INT, did you mean **6458** or **112345**?

I hope this can help you